# Allure reports not showing categories section with webdriverio and cucumber

Tags: webdriver-io, allure

Once I execute the test, allure reports have two problems I am facing.

1. Currently Categories is showing as empty. There is nothing in that tab.
2. In suites section, the testbody is shown with request and response messages. How can I change with test steps and screenshots.

[Categories Shown empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWvWM.png)

[image: Suites tab - test body showing request and response alone]

Answer (score 1):

Categories tabs shows failing tests. Actually you don't have any failing tests